# Common code from build.gradle(Module) extract into top-level build.gradle(Project)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

my IDE is android studio 2.2

i want to extract the common code from build.gradle(Module) into top-level build.gradle(Project) for common use.

i tried subprojects block as below, but it not work:

```
subprojects {

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.9'
            classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9'
    }
}
```

i get this error:

*Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.9] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my finally solution:

create a gradle plugin to do this work, just like [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo/blob/master/hugo-plugin/src/main/groovy/hugo/weaving/plugin/HugoPlugin.groovy).
tanks JakeWharton, thanks [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo)